# Send HTML email along with multiple file attachments?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am trying to send an HTML email in the body of an email along with few file attachments as well. I came up with below code:

```
public void sendEmail(final String to, final String from, final String cc, final String subject, final String body,
        final String baseDirectory, final List<String> listOfFileNames) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { // retrying
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProperties, null);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            InternetAddress[] toAddress = InternetAddress.parse(to);
            InternetAddress[] ccAddress = InternetAddress.parse(cc);

            message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            message.addRecipients(RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(body, "text/html;charset=utf8");

            for (String file : listOfFileNames) {
                String fileLocation = baseDirectory + "/" + file;
                addAttachment(multipart, fileLocation);
            }
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message, toAddress);
            break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}

// this is used for attachment
private void addAttachment(final Multipart multipart, final String filename) throws MessagingException {
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

I need to have body String as part of my HTML email and have all the files attach in the same email. I am running like this as in my home directory, I have two files: `abc.csv` and `tree.txt`.

```
EmailTest.getInstance().sendEmail("hello@host.com", "hello@host.com", "hello@host.com",
                "Test Subject (" + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ")", content, "/export/home/david/",
                Arrays.asList("abc.csv", "tree.txt"));
```

After I get an email, I don't see my text in the body of an email at all? And second thing is file attachment name is coming as `/export/home/david/abc.csv` and `/export/home/david/tree.txt`?

Is anything wrong I am doing? One thing I see wrong as I am calling `setContent` method twice with different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add the text as an own `BodyPart`. Next your `MimeMultipart` needs to be set to the type r`elated` so you can have both, HTML-Text and some attachements. Then it should work to have both, attachements and text.

And the filename you pass to `messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename)` is the filename you see in the attachment name. So just leave out the path and you should just see `abc.csv` and `tree.txt`

```
public void sendEmail(final String to, final String from, final String cc, final String subject, final String body,
        final String baseDirectory, final List<String> listOfFileNames) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { // retrying
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProperties, null);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
            MimeBodyPart bodyPart= new MimeBodyPart();

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            InternetAddress[] toAddress = InternetAddress.parse(to);
            InternetAddress[] ccAddress = InternetAddress.parse(cc);

            message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            message.addRecipients(RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);
            message.setSubject(subject);

            bodyPart.setText(body, "UTF-8", "html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

            for (String file : listOfFileNames) {
                String fileLocation = baseDirectory + "/" + file;
                addAttachment(multipart, fileLocation, file);
            }
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message, toAddress);
            break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}

// this is used for attachment
private void addAttachment(final Multipart multipart, final String filepath, final String filename) throws MessagingException {
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filepath);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is one small confusion in the `addAttachment` method. You have two same name parameters so I am getting confuse which one is for what and where to use.

Comment: @user1950349 oh yeah. Sorry my fault. I have edited one of them. It should work now

Comment: cool, it works fine. Also, let's say if the `listOfFileNames` is empty but we have  something in the body, then it will send an email with all its body in HTML form but the attachments will not be there right?

Comment: yes, correct. If there are no attachments added, then you will just see the text

Comment: You should only use multipart/related if the attachments are referenced by the html text using "cid:" URLs.  In your case I believe they are not, so just plain multipart/mixed (the default) should be used.